# Auto-reload of compiled classes in Tomcat 8 debug mode

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, hotswap

In my application all compiled classes are put under WEB-INF/classes. I am trying to set up Tomcat so that it picks up changes in class files without reloading the context. The latter works by adding `reloadable="true"` to `<Context>` configuration, but context reload still takes too much time.

Seems that basic hotswap (changes in existing methods) can work when running Tomcat in debug mode via

```
bin/catalina.sh jdpa start
```

Still, when Tomcat is thus started, recompilation does not affect things. I've tested it by modifying existing logger statements - they remain similar as before Tomcat was actually started. Can someone please point me to the cause of the problem?

I'm not using Eclipse, but text editor and Gradle to run the builds.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you interpret JVM feature incorrectly... hot-swap must be performed by an attached debugger (e.g. by Eclipse). This i not a feature on its own.

Comment: Thank you for comment. You are right - i was wrong in assuming that hotswap was possible without a debugger. Oh well:)

Comment: You might try [Spring-Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded). This will add class reloading capability to your server.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "bin/catalina.sh j**pd**a start"?